# Drop ALL rows in pandas until a specific string is found then stop dropping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to delete every row until a specific string is found.

I have tried a couple things but nothing seems to be working. Here is what I have tried:

```
df[((df.Plate != 'Group Summaries'))]
df.loc[: df[(df['Plate:'] == 'Group Summaries')].index[0], :]
df[(df['Plate:'] == "Group Summaries").idxmax():]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you find the first index where this case appears and then delete all previous row?

```py
import pandas as pd

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Plate": ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "c", "c"]})

# First index where values is c
idx = df.index[df["Plate"].eq("c")].min()

# Drop previous rows
df = df[idx:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[df['Plate'].eq('Group Summaries').cummax()]
```

How it works:

- mark True the rows with "Group Summaries" in the "Plate" column
- forward the True to all next rows with `cummax`
- use boolean indexing to select the rows

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess I need to be more concise with my question. I am wanting all the rows to be deleted until the first instance of "Group Summaries" is found in my "Plate" column. The code you suggested did not work. Nothing was deleted and my code broke.

Comment: @animosityheals it doesn't "delete" in place, it returns a DataFrame with only the desired rows. I'm not sure how you used it in your code but you need to assign the output: `df2 = df[df['Plate'].eq('Group Summaries').cummax()]`

Comment: I created a new variable df2 but now it is empty. Is it deleting all my data now? I just want all the rows before a certain string to be deleted. I am confused on why the new dataframe is empty

Comment: @animosityheals hard to debug without an example, please provide a minimal one